# About GCM/FCM endpoint

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

In our project we use GCM for Push notification.
Because migration to FCM is recommended, FCM transition of server function is considered.
Please tell me about questions ① and ② below.

① About GCM endpoint
    We are using "android.googleapis.com".
    In the following URL (FCM official website), the GCM end point is written as "gcm-http.googleapis.com", and we do not have "android.googleapis.com" written.
    In offcial website, There is no mention of our useing GCM endpoint "android.googleapis.com".

```
 ·Https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_server_endpoints
```

Q1. Does "android.googleapis.com" continue to be supported and available?
         Is "android.googleapis.com" going to be deprecated?

Q2. Is "android.googleapis.com" an endpoint for GCM 2.0?

---

② About difference of GCM, FCM end point
    Submit the request to the sendAPI at the endpoint below push notification could be done at all endpoints.

```
1) android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
2) gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
3) fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Q3. When the same request is sent to the above API, will the same response be returned?

Q4. When the same response is returned, what is the difference between the above APIs(1～3)?

Q5. Also, although official website recommends shifting to FCM, is there any meaning to switch the endpoint(1～3)?

Answer (score 4):

All three domain names map to the same server IP today. You should assume that only the fcm subdomain will be available after April 19th 2019.

Comment: Thats good to know. So, we safely can switch to new endpoint and older GCM installs will be working OK?

Comment: My understanding from the docs is that FCM will support GCM until April 2019. After that older installs will no longer work.

Comment: That should be fine, there should be no old installs by then, but while people upgrading new FCM endpoint should be OK for them (next couple 3-4-5 month..)